# Access denied for user in WordPress installation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

After uploading my WordPress installation in remote server, there are some queries that stop working (in MAMP they use to work perfectly).

```html
<label for="regione_riferimento"><strong>Regione:</strong></label><br>
<select id="regione_riferimento" name="regione_riferimento" style="overflow:hidden; width:100%;">
    <option value="null">.: Nessuna regione :.</option>
    <?php
    $sql_regioni = "SELECT * FROM bt_regioni ORDER BY regione ASC";
    $query_regioni = mysql_query($sql_regioni);
    if (!$query_regioni) {echo mysql_error();}
    while ($regioni = mysql_fetch_array($query_regioni)) {
        $regione = $regioni['regione']; $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $regione; ?>" <?php if ($regione == $regione_riferimento) {echo $selected;}?>>
        <?php echo $regione;?></option><?php }
    ?>
</select><br>
```

I'm receiving this error:

> Access denied for user 'thor'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I think that replace `localhost` by ip address or name of the Database.

Comment: It keeps on not working :(